# How to run Bitcoin Core and what folders to move to my second VM after having it successfully running on my first VM?

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux

I've Bitcoin Core v22.0 running smoothly on my first VM.

Now I want to have Bitcoin Core up and running on my second VM but without syncing the blockchain from scratch as I did with the first VM to save bandwidth.

So what files/folders should I move to the second VM and after moving those files/folders, what shall I do after I install Bitcoin Core?

The two VMs are running Linux Mint 20.3

Thank you.